# Angular 6 / AngularFire migration

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire5, angular6

**I have the following older Angular 4 code:**

The *navigation.component.ts* file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { LogoComponent } from './logo.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})

export class NavigationComponent {
    items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.items = db.list('/pages', { 
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'sortOrder',
                limitToLast: 100
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The *navigation.component.html* file (truncated for brevity):

```
<nav class="nav-standard">
    <app-logo></app-logo>
    <div class="nav-dropdown">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of items | async | filter : 'parent' : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="nav-narrow">
    <app-logo></app-logo>
    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu" class="nav-dropdown nav-narrow-dropdown">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of items | async | filter : 'parent' : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="nav-dropdown nav-narrow-dropdown">
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>   
    </md-menu>
    <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="expand-button">
        <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>
</nav>
```

**which I am trying to convert to Angular 6 [and got this far]:**

The *navigation.component.ts* file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { LogoComponent } from './logo.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})

export class NavigationComponent {
    items: AngularFireList<any[]>;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.items = db.list('/pages');
    }
}
```

The *navigation.component.html* file (truncated for brevity):

```
<nav class="nav-standard">
    <app-logo></app-logo>
    <div class="nav-dropdown">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of items | async | filter : 'parent' : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="nav-narrow">
    <app-logo></app-logo>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="nav-dropdown nav-narrow-dropdown">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of items | async | filter : 'parent' : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="nav-dropdown nav-narrow-dropdown">
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>   
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="expand-button">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
</nav>
```

This is throwing an error:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4238)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4845)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:4835)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4817)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NavigationComponent.html:4)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11922)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11315)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11321)

It appears that switching to the new AngularFireList is breaking the *ngFor*?   I am a bit confused as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async pipe subscribes to Observable or Promise. In your case, 'items' is only a reference to the AngularFireList object. You probably need to turn it into an Observable:

```
    items: Observable<any[]>;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.items = db.list('/pages').valueChanges();
    }
```

Comment: This worked.   Now, what would the syntax be to return the item $key?  I currently have, but not sure how to do the "map" to add item $key metadata in:
`export class NavigationComponent {
 items: Observable<any[]>;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.items = db.list('/pages', ref => {
            let query = ref.limitToLast(100).orderByChild('sortOrder');
            return query;
        }).valueChanges();
    }
}`

Comment: Opened a new question for this follow-on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192924/returning-key-in-angularfire-5

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are using different versions of angularfire2:

```
OLD 4.0
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  db.list('items').subscribe(console.log);
}
NEW 5.0
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  db.list('items').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
}
```

More info: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md